# Don't Add Indesign Tags to the root element?

Tags: javascript, xml, adobe-indesign, extendscript

following code example:

```
var myDocument = app.documents.add();
var myTextFrame = myDocument.pages.item(0).textFrames.add();
myTextFrame.geometricBounds = ["6p", "6p", "24p", "24p"];
myTextFrame.contents = "Hello World!";

myBounds = myTextFrame.geometricBounds;


var myX = "" + myBounds[1];
var myY = "" + myBounds[0];

var myTag = myDocument.xmlTags.add("text-area");

var myXMLElement =  myDocument.xmlElements.item(0).xmlElements.add(myTag, myTextFrame);
myXMLElement.xmlAttributes.add("x", myX);
myXMLElement.xmlAttributes.add("y", myY);
```

This will give out the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root><text-area x="25.4" y="25.4000000000001">Hello World!</text-area></Root>
```

Can I somehow not show the root tag? Delete it or don't let it show up in the .xml? I searched for different keywords but I couldn't find the solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every document has a new root element by default. If you grab the first `xmlElement`, that's the root element. Here's an example of the changes you would make to have `text-area` be the root element:

```
var myDocument = app.documents.add();
var myTextFrame = myDocument.pages[0].textFrames.add();
myTextFrame.geometricBounds = ["6p", "6p", "24p", "24p"];
myTextFrame.contents = "Hello World!";

var myRootElem = myDocument.xmlElements[0];
myRootElem.markupTag.name = "text-area";

var myBounds = myTextFrame.geometricBounds;
var myX = "" + myBounds[1];
var myY = "" + myBounds[0];

myRootElem.xmlAttributes.add("x", myX);
myRootElem.xmlAttributes.add("y", myY);

myTextFrame.markup(myRootElem);
```

Comment: Okay this could eventually work. Is this only possible for each document, or as well for each page in a document?

Comment: It doesn't look like that's possible. InDesign gives an error message when trying to add multiple root elements.

Comment: Damn... Thank you anyways for your answer, Ill give u a thumbs up :P

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help!

Comment: Actually this is the right answer, as you said "no its not possible".

Comment: FYI only; InDesign is correct in refusing this. A well-formed XML tree has "a single "root" element that contains all other elements": see [the Offical Definition of well-formednessness](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed) under *Document*, item 2.

Comment: Well, I don't think "correct in refusing" is the right term here. There are always in every programming language cases in which u can't or don't want to use the standard. And in this case it just would have been nice to have the configuration to not use any root element. Xml is so flexible and can be used in so many cases, that I don't really think it is useful to always have a root element.

Comment: But in this case it is the exact reason that you cannot do it. (To be honest, InDesign *barely* can handle XMl. Its super-handy built-in XSLT, for example, is severly limited.)

Comment: I've noticed that too. We've had trouble in the past trying to get InDesign to process XML well without crashing or choking.